# How do you store your equipment?

Tags: equipment-protection, equipment-storage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are good schemes for storing photo equipment at home?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3719/what-are-good-schemes-for-storing-photo-equipment-at-home)

As my photographic equipment is getting bigger (new lenses, new addons, new bodies) I think I need a better storing solution. **Currently I just keep all my stuff in a desk drawer**.

How do you store your cameras and lenses? Just to clarify, I don't mean storing it for a long time, I mean when you just stop using the camera for the day (or week).

**Bags? Boxes? Bigger desk drawers?**

Comment: See also: http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/3719/21